# How to filter based on contains all in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a data frame :

```
val df = Seq(
    ("A",11,5),
    ("A",12,10),
    ("A",13,1),
    ("B",11,5),
    ("B",14,5),
    ("B",13,5)
    ).toDF("id","type","value")

df.groupBy($"id").agg(collect_set("value")).show(false)

+---+------------------+
|id |collect_set(value)|
+---+------------------+
|B  |[5]               |
|A  |[1, 5, 10]        |
+---+------------------+
```

I need to filter the ids(or count of unique ids) which have all the values in the set are lesser than 5 (or any number). For e.g. In the above the df 
only B have all value lesser than 5.

Can some one tell me how do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupBy($"id")
  .agg(collect_set("value"), max($"value").as("max_value"))
  .filter($"max_value" <= 5)
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer.